# Bubble and Selection Sort

Tags: java, bubble-sort, selection-sort

I'm currently working on my bubble and selection sorts and ran into a couple problems. I've received help from a couple of fellow friends and now on my own, I'm stuck. I already have the bubble sort, so I brought the following code into my selection code. But had a different algorithm for the selection part.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.*;

public class SelectionSort 
{
int a[];
int n;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  int array[] = { 5,3,9,7,1,8 };
  System.out.println(""+Arrays.toString(Sort(array)));
}

public static int[] Sort(int[] arr)
{
  int t, min;
  for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
  min = i;
  for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
{
  if(a[min]>a[j])
  min = j;
}
  if(min!=i)
{
  t = a[min];
  a[min] = a[i];
  a[i] = t;
}
System.out.println(""+Arrays.toString(arr));
}
return arr;
}

}
```

The bubble code works perfectly, I also have to output every change that happens throughout the code.

```
[3, 5, 7, 1, 8, 9]
[3, 5, 1, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 1, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who assists me!

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question

Comment: How do I fix my code, isn't that a question?

Comment: @tshes you have to ask a well focused question!just asking to fix your code is not nice right? we need more information like what actually goes wrong, what have you tried.

Comment: Sorry to seem rude, I'm just worried about my code. I've tried to change the code, I've asked a friend and he said that I haven't declared the variables, but I have. My overall question is why won't it compile, it's giving me errors that i'm not receive in my bubble sort.

Comment: Well one thing right off the bat your friend was right you do not give "n" a value to start with and yet you are using it as a loop boundary.  Might want to fix that and your code might stop throwing errors

Comment: Does your code have a compiler error or a runtime exception? Please post the exact error and the stack trace (if any). Does it produce the wrong data? In which case, please post the output.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `n` variable non-static, so static method `Sort` can't access to `n`. Try to change signature to `static int n` and initialize it in `main`: `n = 6`.

Answer (score 0):

You know you could just use `Arrays.sort(yourList);`